# Set auto height in PHPExcel not working

Tags: php, yii, yii2, phpexcel

I am generating Excel using PHPExcel.

All Code Works Fine.But Auto height code is not Working.

I have tried following code.

Apply row height on specific row

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('7')->setRowHeight(-1);
```

Apply row height on for all row

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
```

I have also tried word wrap property with it.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('B7')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setWrapText(true);
```

But it give me result as below:

[image]

> Note : Working in MS office,Not Working in Apache open Office and
>   LibreOffice

Comment: Set you cell properties to wrap text as well, otherwise auto height alone is not enough

Comment: @MarkBaker, i have also tried word wrap property and auto height

Comment: What Writer are you using?

Comment: And row height will never work for an individual cell address, nor for a default row dimension with a specified row.... `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);` or `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);`

Comment: @MarkBaker, Thanks,I have tried your both way but it is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122648/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-mark-baker).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have just added the following to the 01simple.php example

```
$value = "To be or not to be-that is the question: whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, or to take arms against a sea of troubles, and, by opposing, end them."; 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A12', $value); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(12)->setRowHeight(-1); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A12')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

and this creates correctly wrapped output for both Excel2007 and Excel5 Writers

Comment: Thanks,but Not Working

Comment: Same as above output

Comment: Then give me some clues to help me figure out what is going wrong.... if I can't replicate a problem, then I cannot fix it, and I've been testing this for fifteen minutes now without any problems..... what are you doing that's different to what I'm doing that could cause a problem?

Comment: Given that you've edited your question, and the picture you posted has been changed, you are actually getting word wrap now.... so edit it again, and show the actual code that you're using

Comment: dude, i did it first but change for you

Comment: i am setting height for row and it is working , just auto height is not working

Comment: I still don't know what your'e doing that is different to what I did, because setting autoheight has worked perfectly every time I've tried in the last 20 minutes..... show what you are actually doing!

Comment: So are you checking this in MS Excel, or in Open/LibreOffice?

Comment: I have Checked in Both, but i want to saw you that many coder facing this issue.

Comment: So does it work in MS Excel or not? And shoudl the PHPExcel library be responsible for fixing bugs in LibreOffice?

Comment: Well! It works for me in MS Excel, so which version of  MS Excel are you testing against? Are you still talking about Excel 2007? Does it work for you if you use Excel5 Writer?

Comment: Sorry,In MS excel now it is working ,but not working in Apache open office and LibreOffice

Comment: [This is a known bug in Open/LibreOffice](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272177/does-anyone-know-how-to-wrap-text-in-a-cell-in-libreoffice-calc)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, is there any solution for it.

Comment: There isn't, not while the bug exists in LibreOffice... PHPExcel writes its output in the correct format

Comment: ok, update your answer so i can accept it. and other people can know it

Comment: @MarkBaker This one works for wrapping single cells in a row. But how can I wrap a cell merged across a row (on which `setRowHeight(-1)` is applied)?

Comment: @Yogesh Mistry I have the same problem

Comment: @Mark Baker I need your help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469303/how-do-i-make-automatic-height-row-based-on-content-in-the-maatwebsite-version-3